# Shared temporary file location

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

We develop applications/sequences on Windows laptops but the ESB servers are Linux based. In case we have to deal with handling files we store them in a temporary location. Windows and Linux have different filesystems and using hardcoded locations works on one platform but not the other.

How can I create and use a kind of TempLocation environment variable, registry entry or else that we can use but that does not change after deployments or server restarts or cause conflicts between applications.

Regards,
Paul

Comment: How about using SVN GIT?

Comment: With handling files I mean files that are processed by the ESB mediators. The files require temporary storage, probably for just a few seconds. That file location (/tmp on Linux for example) must be configurable over environments easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what your goal for store the files? But I think you maybe can use the carbon home. You can create the "tempFiles" folder under your Linux and Windows ESB home. Then use the `CarbonUtils` get the the carbon home.

```
String carbonhome = org.wso2.carbon.utils.CarbonUtils.getCarbonHome();
```

You may need use the `File.separator` for append the folder path.

```
String tempPath = carbonhome + File.separator +"tempFiles";
```

Then use the Java IO store your files on this folder. But you may need proper access for this folder.

In case you need the Maven dependency for `CarbonUtils`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wso2.carbon</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.wso2.carbon.utils</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The files are stored temporarily. Thanks for the suggestion.